# Java Communcation API not available for Windows

Tags: java, communication

I want to write a program in Java using RS-232. But I am unable to find the java.comm Package for the windows. Which library should I use for this purpose?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-misc-419423.html

The only package avaiable here are not for Windows. Can you please guide me as I am new to this kind of development.

Using rxtx + java I got this code from the internet

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
public class SimpleWrite 
{
public static void main (String args[])
{

    Enumeration port_list = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    System.out.println(port_list);

    while (port_list.hasMoreElements())
    {
        CommPortIdentifier port_id = (CommPortIdentifier)port_list.nextElement();

        if (port_id.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
        {
            System.out.println ("Serial port:" + port_id.getName());
        }
        else if (port_id.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL)
        {
            System.out.println ("Parallel port:" + port_id.getName());
        }
        else
            System.out.println ("Other port:" + port_id.getName());
    }
} 
}
```

But this code gives me error of gnu.io.rxtx.properties has not been detected.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries written for this, just google for `rxtx + java`. One of the alive ones seems to be http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/ .

Comment: I have tried the rxtx + java But I am unable to find any clear steps. Like I have placed the Rxtxcomm and rxtxserial.dll to the specified locations. But when I run the program it gives me error that gnu.io.rxtx.properties has not been detected. And I think that there offical website is also not working http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Examples

Comment: Just edited my question.

Comment: Well, it might be e.g. missing or wrong (x86/x64) binaries, I don't know. Yes, rxtx site is down. One of the alive ones seems to be java-simple-serial-connector. Have yo tried it?